# MYSQL - PDO with multiple IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can successfully implement a IN clause within a PDO prepared statement using the following code.

```
in_array = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($in_array) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_value IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($in_array);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

How can I do the same for multiple $in? For example I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
in_array1 = array(1,2,3);
$in1  = str_repeat('?,', count($in_array) - 1) . '?';
in_array2 = array(4,5,1);
$in2  = str_repeat('?,', count($in_array) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_value1 IN ($in1)) AND (my_value2 IN ($in2))";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($in_array1,$in_array2);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

I think its got to do with stm->execute but not sure, help appreciated

Comment: `execute()` takes **1** parameter, which are the arguments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query comes out as

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_value1 IN (?,?,?)) AND (my_value2 IN (?,?,?))
```

So your `execute` usage is incorrect, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php. It should only be passing one array with values inside it.

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

I think using array_merge, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php, will allow you to accomplish what you are trying

```
$stm->execute(array_merge($in_array1,$in_array2));
```

This way the execute is the equivalent of

```
$stm->execute(array(1,2,3,4,5,1));
```

This may seem incorrect because the array pairings are now gone but placeholder 1 (the first question mark) will map to `1`, placeholder 4 to `4`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me. Honestly I didn't understand the purpose of placing the array in the execute(), but now I know its got to do with the placeholders which now makes sense! This has saved me from trying to do a query in a for loop, thanks again!

Comment: What to do both $in_array1 and $in_array2 are the same ?

Comment: @Subin It should still merge fine, no? Can you make a sample of your issue, or do you have an open question?

Comment: @chris85 Well if the array is same, the keys will be same and merged array will be equal to one array. I had to use this to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591120/1372424

Comment: @Subin Not reproducing here https://3v4l.org/bcXY1... or maybe I'm not following. What do you mean by `merged array will be equal to one array`, thats the purpose of the merge.

Comment: @chris85 I don't know why. But a simple array_merge didn't work. Instead doing array_values first and then array_merge worked.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make sense.
Look at this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 = ? AND value2 = ?");
$query ->execute(array($value1, $value2));
```

and this:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php