# Same array multiple times in MySQL "IN" query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I need to execute an "IN" query which has a list of elements (array) twice using PDO in order to avoid SQL Injection.
The query that I need is:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user 
WHERE google_id IN ('123123123abacaa','123bac21') 
   OR facebook_id IN ('123123123abacaa','123bac21');
```

As you can see, the list of elements is always the same.
But I don't know how to asign my array to the second "IN" statement, PHP throws me an "Invalid parameter number" error.
Here is my code:

```
$list = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT user_id 
        FROM user 
        WHERE google_id IN (".$list.") 
          OR facebook_id IN (".$list.");";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_values($ids));
```

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: A bit different of the provided "possible duplicated" because I need to use the array two times in the SQL clause

SOLUTION: As @u_mulder say it's easily solved by changing the "execute" statement for:

```
$stmt->execute(array_merge(array_values($ids), array_values($ids)));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO - Invalid parameter number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408037/pdo-invalid-parameter-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can just merge array of your params with itself:

```
$stmt->execute(array_merge(array_values($ids), array_values($ids)));
```

Comment: If my answer helped you there - accept it, no need to edit your question with a solution.